# wrong python version shown inside VSCode

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, zsh, pyenv

I created a virtual env using this method within my VSCode Studio.

```
pyenv install 3.7.4
pyenv virtualenv 3.7.4 apps3
pyenv local apps3
pyenv activate apps3
```

However, when I check `python --version`after the last command, it still shows me `Python 2.7.16`, which is my default shell version.

However, if I try to activate the env in another terminal (outside VSCode), I am able to see the correct version. How can I fix it within VSCode?

Within VSCode, I see these:

```
which python
/usr/bin/python
```

Path after activating:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv-virtualenv/1.1.5/shims:/Users/neehahammad/.pyenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/bin:/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/condabin:/Users/nh/.local/bin:/Users/nh/.local/bin
```

Path without environment activated:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv-virtualenv/1.1.5/shims:/Users/neehahammad/.pyenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/bin:/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/condabin:/Users/nh/.local/bin:/Users/nh/.local/bin
```

already added this in the .zschrc file

```
$ export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
$ eval "$(pyenv init -)"
$ eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

`which python` from another terminal (outside VS):

```
/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/bin/python
```

Comment: VSCode does not get anything from `.zshrc` unless you launch it from a shell. A process inherits environment variables from the process that launched it.

Comment: so, what's the solution? since I created the virtual env within the VS code, shouldn't it already work there? @molbdnilo

Comment: Well, it should. There's a setting in VSCode about inheriting the environment in the VSCode terminal. Search for "environment" and locate "Inherit Env" for the terminal. Make sure that it's checked and start a new shell.

Comment: it's already checked. also tried reloading and updating VS code but it's still showing the wrong version @molbdnilo